# How to implement Markdown style link IDs in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

At times, I need to use the same link at multiple places in a long document.

For those cases it would be useful to have link IDs like in markdown. From [markdown syntax ref](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link),

> You can optionally use a space to separate the sets of brackets:
>
> ```
> This is [an example] [id] reference-style link.
> ```
>
> Then, anywhere in the document, you define your link label like this, on a line by itself:
>
> ```
> [id]: http://example.com/ "Optional Title Here"
> ```

I believed that the [Link Abbreviation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Link-abbreviations.html#Link-abbreviations) in org-mode would work the same way (without tags) but it doesn't.

The purpose of link IDs is to have a central place for editing the links. A good location would be at the end of the document. Full links are defined in the ID but only the ID is used elsewhere in the document where we need to place the hyperlinks.
When exporting, the IDs are replaced with the actual hyperlinks.

Benefits of this approach are,

- When the links change, we need to just modify the ID definitions. On exporting, the hyperlinks in the document will be updated to that.
- Faster hyperlink insertion when writing the document as one doesn't have to get and paste the full links every time. You type the IDs in the document and define them in a block at the end of the document.

Comment: Is this for usage or for export?

Comment: The usage is for exports. The aim is to have one place to edit the link and just use the ID where I want to place the hyperlinks. For now I resort to just using org mode MACROs that expand to `[[Link][Link Name]]` . But the ID approach like in Markdown will be cleaner.

Comment: That looks a lot like a footnote to me. Some other possibilities that might work are radio targets (http://orgmode.org/manual/Radio-targets.html#Radio-targets) or internal links to <<targets>> http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html#Internal-links.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[This page](http://endlessparentheses.com/use-org-mode-links-for-absolutely-anything.html)
has a nice description on how to extend org-mode links. It doesn’t
address your specific concern, but it explains the basic principle.
Let’s say we want your links to be defined like this, anywhere in the buffer,

```
#+LINK-ID: wiki http://www.emacswiki.org
```

and invoked like this

```
[[lid:wiki][You should check out the wiki]]
```

First, you need to tell org how to follow and how to export your link.

```
(org-add-link-type "lid" 'endless/open-id-link 'endless/export-id-link)

(defun endless/open-id-link (path)
  "Follow an ID link to PATH."
  (browse-url (endless/find-id-link path)))

(defun endless/export-id-link (path desc format)
  "Create the export version of an ID link specified by PATH and DESC.
FORMATs understood are 'latex and 'html."
  (setq path (endless/find-id-link path))
  (cond
   ((eq format 'html) (format "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" path desc))
   ((eq format 'latex) (format "\\href{%s}{%s}" path desc))
   (t desc)))
```

Then, you just need to decide how *you* want to handle this link.

```
(defun endless/find-id-link (id &optional noerror)
  "Find \"#+LINK-ID: ID\" in current buffer and return the link.
Unless NOERROR is non-nil, throw an error if link not found."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((case-fold-search t))
      (when (search-forward-regexp 
             (format "^#\\+LINK-ID: \\b%s\\b +\\(.*\\) *$" id)
             nil noerror)
        (match-string-no-properties 1)))))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the title you mentioned in the would be used for. If you let me know I can add it in.

Comment: I notice that for the existing export function examples: docview, bbdb, along the `org-add-link-type` function call, they also do `(add-hook 'org-store-link-functions 'org-LINKTYPE-store-link)`.