# Is there an easy way to edit all links in an org file?

Tags: org-mode

I have an org file with several dozen links to various webpages. I'd like to view and edit most of the urls in this file. Is there a convenient way to do this?

In other words, does org-mode have a feature that allows me to view and edit all the links in my document in one place?

Comment: Do you want an automated way (e.g., "each link is something like whatever.com; change it to http://whatever.com"), or a way to prompt you for the edit to each link, then automatically move to the next link?

Comment: I'm curious if there is a feature in org-mode that allows me to conveniently view all the urls in one place.

Comment: [This](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/594/115) isn't a solution to your current problem. But it will help you list all the URLs at the end of the documents going forward. I use this approach so that I can review/edit the links as needed easily as they all are present in section of the file.

Comment: @kaushalmodi That looks like a pretty useful way for me to structure documents in the future.

Answer (score 9):

It's all plain text, so just use a normal search-and-replace.

If `org-mode` manages to suppress that somehow, just temporarily change the major mode. e.g. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `fundamental-mode`

Edit:

Actually, assuming you're on Emacs 24.1+, `occur-edit-mode` will be a nice way to do that, as you'll see the plain text link syntax in the occur buffer, and only the lines you're interested in.

- <kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> `<regexp>` <kbd>RET</kbd> (for whatever pattern matches the links you want to edit)
- Switch to the `*Occur*` buffer.
- <kbd>e</kbd> (enter `occur-edit-mode`)
- Do any editing you need to do. Search and replace, etc. (n.b. You'll need to move point down off the first line of the occur buffer.)
- <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> (confirm the changes and exit `occur-edit-mode`)
- Return to and save the original buffer.

Edit 2:

If you aren't picky about which links you're searching for, you could run a command like this:

```el
(defun my-org-links-occur ()
  "Run `occur' for all `org-mode' links in the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (occur org-any-link-re))
```

Comment: My issue isn't that I can't see the urls, it's mainly that I have a large number of urls in the file and I'd like to view them all in one place so I can parse them.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick You can see the links too if you enable the `visible-mode` (toggle using `M-x visible-mode`)... and use this regexp: `\[\[.*?\]\[.*?\]\]` for the `occur`.

Comment: Brian: It looks like you commented just slightly before I added the info on `occur`. "[viewing] them all in one place" is exactly what `occur` is for, so I imagine it suits your purposes quite well.

Comment: You could also use `org-occur` instead of regular `occur` (it will preserve more context around links).  Also there's `org-toggle-link-display` to toggle between how Org links are displayed.