# How can I get all file links in one org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

There are some local file links existed randomly in my org-mode file. most of them are image links, like (file:images/samples.png) along with some other urls. What I want to do is that parse all these links from the file and store them in a lisp list for afterwards use.

Here is a sample file:

```
* headline1
  [[file:images/sample1.png][description1]]
* headline2
  [[file:images/sample2.png][description2]]
  [[http://www.google.com]]
```

After parsing, a list of all file links should obtained.

```
(list "images/sample1.png" "images/sample1.png")
```

Comment: All what file links? Where are the files located?

Comment: The links randomly distribute in all the org-mode file. Actually, I would like to find a function to find all the links, and store them in a list.

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/16781/115

Comment: @kaushalmodi thanks, but i would like to do it in program way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the current buffer is an org-mode buffer,
the following code collects paths of file links in the current buffer.

```
(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link
  (lambda (link)
    (when (string= (org-element-property :type link) "file")
      (org-element-property :path link))))
```

In an org buffer, `(org-element-parse-buffer)` returns the parse
tree of the current buffer.
And you can map over it with `org-element-map`.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in command for such searching is `org-occur`.

org-occur <kbd>RET</kbd> file: <kbd>RET</kbd>

will return a org tree of file links in current buffer. See the org manual for options with this command and how you can customize the regex search.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer by @sho.

```lisp
(defun jlp/org-link-info (link)
  (let ((path (org-element-property :path link))
        (type (org-element-property :type link))
        (desc (substring-no-properties (nth 2 link))))
    (list type path desc)))
```

Then use

```lisp
(org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer) 'link 'jlp/org-link-info)
```

This will return a list of all links in the buffer of format

```lisp
(list
  (list link-type link-path link-description))
```

You can then filter by link type `file`,`fuzzy`,`elisp`,etc using `nth 0`, pull all the links (for example to open in bulk) using `nth 1` and the descriptions `nth 2`.