# how to get org-mode to recognize markdown-style links?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, hyperlinks

I'd like to get org-mode to recognize hyperlinks written in Markdown syntax, that is, links in this format:

`[markdown link syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)`

How do I add the markdown hyperlink type to org-mode?

Related but different:
[How to implement Markdown style link IDs in org-mode?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/how-to-implement-markdown-style-link-ids-in-org-mode)

Probably helpful: http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html

Answer (score 3):

Well this has bugged me a lot too (I happen to find the Markdown syntax much more intuitive), and today I looked into the required changes to org.el and there's quite some work.

- There should be an `org-angle-link-re` in `org-make-link-regexps` similar to the other link types,
- And then it would need to be plumbed down *everywhere*:

  - into `org-any-link-re` in that same function `org-make-link-regexps`,
  - a function `org-activate-markdown-links` would need to be written and plumbed down into `org-set-font-lock-defaults`, with further plumbing required to make the `org-highlight-links` work,
- And then of course, it would be testing and debugging time.

It doesn't look like one can get away with a couple of `defadvice`s, so there would need to be a patch, that would immediately start bit-rotting unless it somehow gets accepted upstream. Which sounds like a tough sell ☹

Comment: I feel like it should be possible through this: http://orgmode.org/manual/Adding-hyperlink-types.html